# Environment inconsistency error using conda install in AWS jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I want to use conda to install transformers in AWS Sagemaker terminal.

When I ran `conda install transformers`, I keep getting environment inconsistency errors:[image: Error message]

I also tried other commands suggested online such as `conda update --all`, but as long as it's a conda command, it will show environment is inconsistent.

How should I fix this? (I cannot use pip install, as it shows "dead kernel" error whenever running transformers model)